# Android - non UI thread does not run properly - async thread satured singleton in main ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite

I have a big sql database, so I do the sql work on non-ui thread. However, it seems to be the non-ui thread always run on ui thread.

```
/* MyDBHelper is singleton */
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    /* Singleton code here*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        buildDatabaseFromFile(db, "create.sql");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        buildDatabaseFromFile(db, "update.sql");
    }

    private void buildDatabaseFromFile(final SQLiteDatabase db, final String filePath) {
        onSqlExecution = true;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            /* sql code here + callback in main ui activity */
        }).start();
    }
}

public class MainActivity() extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyDBHelper.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (onSqlExecution)
            /* new progress dialog here */
    }

    void callback() {
        /* run on ui thread : dismiss progress dialog here */
    }
}
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: how are you saying "However, it seems to be the non-ui thread always run on ui thread"?

Comment: my app frezee : black or white screen without progress dialog. right?

Comment: how are you calling the callback function ?

Comment: I do an Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)

Comment: can you update the post with the actual code that you are using to call the function callback() inside main activity ?

Comment: I just try with AsyncTask, and it's the same. Maybe the sql file in Asset folder broke my code?

Comment: i don't think that should cause any UI freeze